# What is the expected behavior for in-memory data-structures in Spark executors?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to understand if I expect the following behavior properly.

let's say I have 100 executors, each with 4 cores (meaning threads)
I am processing a very large RDD, and the rows inside contain a `some_class` that could be un-valid, if it is - I don't want to process the given row.

I don't want to use a broadcast since the invalid rows are determined to be invalid on the fly (during the RDD processing).

I thought of using an in-memory set and in the worst-case scenario, each executor will one time process a "bad" row - I am ok with that.

am I expecting the behavior properly or am I missing something?

```
val some_set = mutable.HashSet[String]
some_rdd.filterNot(r => some_set.contains(r.some_class.id)
        .map(some_row => {
  try{
    some_def(some_row)
}
catch{
  case e:Throwable => {
     some_set.add(some_row.some_class.id)
     log.info("some error")
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi Roy, what is the size of some_set?

Comment: Hi, 
most of the times it will be 0, but in rare cases, it can be up to 10,000 (rare) 
each element is a String of maximum 20 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example `some_set` will be serialized and sent to the executor together with the task code. Considering the case in which the size of `some_set` is 10.000, then the max task size of your Spark program will be approximately **200KB** (10000 x 20chars). That satisfies the current maximum recommended task size of [1MB](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/492d5d174a435c624bd87af9ee3621f4f1c8d1c5/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/TaskSetManager.scala#L1133). On the other hand, if the task size exceeds 1GB you should expect a warning similar to:

> Stage 1 contains a task of very large size (1024 MB). The maximum
> recommended task size is 1000 KB.

If for some reason the size of `some_set` will increase beyond the limit of 1MB in the future, consider using [broadcasting](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-broadcast-variables/).

**Similar questions**

[How to resolve : Very large size tasks in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37759385/how-to-resolve-very-large-size-tasks-in-spark)

[Spark using python: How to resolve Stage x contains a task of very large size (xxx KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28878654/spark-using-python-how-to-resolve-stage-x-contains-a-task-of-very-large-size-x)

Comment: Hey Abiratsis, thanks for the detailed answer.
Yet my question is referring to the fact each executor has several threads, and I am using a Set which is not synchronized, and I wanted to know if the Set content - 
1. will be different in each executor? 
2. will be shared between different executor threads? 

And not to understand if the size of it is optimal or not

Comment: hey Roy, as I mentioned above the collection will be shipped together with the task code to every executor, therefore will be always the same. No hidden intercommunication will occur between threads or collection sharing. Each thread will process exactly the same set